# Valuations above $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a field, we say that a function $\nu:K\to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$ is a valuation above $K$ if then followings hold for each choose of $x,y \in K$:

1 $\nu(x) = \infty \Leftrightarrow x = 0$;

2 $\nu(xy) = \nu(x) + \nu(y)$;

3 $\nu(x+y) \geq \min\lbrace\nu(x),\nu(y)\rbrace$.

My question is: if we have a field $K$ that cannot be written like the field of fraction of an UFD (I think that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is a field with this property), what can we say about the valuations. I mean

1 Does it always exists a non trivial valuation above $K$?

2 If it exists, what can we say about that, can we describe how the valuations behave? (for further details of "what can we say about that" see below. I consider the Ostrowski theorem sufficiently well describing the how the valuation is "done")

I have an answer in the case in with $K$ IS the field of fraction of an UFD, below I explain the solution in this case.

An observation. If $\alpha$ is a complex algebraic number above $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. it exists a polynomial with rational coefficients among which roots there is $\alpha$), then the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ coincides with the fields of fractions of the domain $\mathbb{Z}(\alpha)$.

We can now analyse some examples.
The $p$-adic valuations are valuations (in the sense of the above definition) above $\mathbb{Q}$.

We can define in an analogous way of the $p$-adic valuations above $\mathbb{Q}$ a family of valuations above a field that is a field of fraction of an unique factorisation domain.
Let's see how. Let $A$ be an UFD and $K$ be its field of fractions.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of prime elements of $A$.
Every nonzero element $x$ of $A$ can be written (identifying the invertibles as one elements) in an unique way like

$x = u\prod_{\pi \in \mathcal{P}}\pi^{\gamma_{\pi}}$,

where $u$ is an invertible element of $A$ and the numbers $\gamma_{\pi}$ are non negative integers.
Let chose a prime element $\pi$ of $A$.
We define the function $\nu_{\pi}:A$, as

$\nu_{\pi}(x) = \gamma_{\pi}$.

We can now extend the domain of the function $\nu_{\pi}$ from $A$ to $K$ defining for each element $a/b \in K$ the value

$\nu_{\pi}(a/b) = \nu_{\pi}(a) - \nu_{\pi}(b)$.

It can be easily be proven that $\nu_{\pi}$ is a valuation.

There is a theorem from Ostrowski that states that every non trivial valuations above $\mathbb{Q}$ must be a $p$-adic valuation for a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ or a $p$-adic valuation multiplied by a rational constant.

I am pretty sure that it can be generalized to a field of fraction of an UFD without problems.
So, if the generalization is true, we have a characterization of all valuations above the field of fractions of an UFD.

Origin of the question:
I am reading an article form Roberts and Vivaldi (http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~fv/research/Height.pdf) and in the proof of the Theorem 1 at pag. 6 they consider a valuation above a quadratic extension of the completion of the rationals with respect to a $p$-adic norm ($p \in \mathbb{Z}$).
I want to know how their valuation is done (and to prove that it exists!). Their situation is different from mine because they have got a valuation above the extension of a completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, while I am working directly with an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. I am doing this way because I do not know too much about the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to some $p$-adic norm beyond the definition and some basic facts.
So if you are not able to find a solution to my problem, for me it would the same if you suppose that the algebraic degree of $\alpha$ above $\mathbb{Z}$ is two or you are able to explain why THEIR valuation exists and how it is done.

Comment: I have deleted my comments because the were about the first formulation of the question, that I have edited because it was bad written.

Comment: IMPORTANT EDIT: it was written $\nu: K \to \mathbb{Z} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$, the CORRECT statement is $\nu: K \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0} \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$

Comment: I made some spelling corrections, but further improvement could be made by positioning the actual questions to be answered earlier in the body of this Question.  Interested Readers have a long way to go before finding out what you want to know about the setup, and I believe that with minor edits these two items could be placed ahead of your examples and "analysis".

Comment: Done, thanks for the corrections.

Comment: Valuations above $v_p$ on $K$ are of the form $v_{\frak p}$ for primes $\frak p$ lying above $p$, defined by $v_{\frak p}(x)=e$ whenever the principal ideal $x{\cal O}_K$ has ${\frak p}^e$ in its factorization into prime ideals. Most books on algebraic number theory should cover this.